# Gradually change opacity based on offset

Tags: jquery, css, opacity

A lot of similar topics but none seemed helpful. I am confronted with a rather simple arithmetic problem but I can't seem to figure it out.

On load an image is displayed X pixels below window top. When the window scrolls the opacity of the element should fade out gradually so that its opacity is `0` the moment it's out of sight (i.e. its offset is < 0). Of course, when a user scrolls back it should then gradually fade in again.

Here is [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/1ypv6e4a/) to play with.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    // Simple example to show something similar
    var d = $("div"),
        offsetT = d.offset().top + d.outerHeight(),
        scrollT = $(document).scrollTop();

    if (offsetT <= scrollT) {
        d.stop(true).fadeOut(1000);
    } else {
        d.stop(true).fadeIn(1000);
    }
    /* What I actually need:
    d.css("opacity", function() {
        // Some arithmetic magic
    });
    */
});
```

The opacity of the element is thus defined by the distance of the element to the window top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var d = $('div'),
      offsetT = d.offset().top + d.outerHeight(),
      scrollT = $(document).scrollTop(),
      y1 = 1, y2 = 0,
      x1 = 0, x2 = offsetT,
      m = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1);

  d.css('opacity', Math.max(0,y1 + m * scrollT));
});
```

It's based on the equation of the line:

[image]

… where `y1` is full opacity when the window is not scrolled, and `y2` is no opacity when the window is scrolled to the bottom of the `div`.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/csr84o8s/)

Comment: This does work nice indeed, however I don't like the negative opacity which you'll no doubtably end up with. Is there any way to by-pass that?

Comment: You could use `Math.max` to prevent negative opacity, but I think a negative opacity will be ignored.  I've updated the answer.

Comment: I think so too, but just to be sure! Thanks. +1 and accept.